# Programmatically jump to a specific block and move the focus/caret to a decorated word

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

Is it possible to programmatically jump to a specific block and move a focus/caret to a decorated word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can set the text selection with EditorState.forceSelection:

```
let selection = new SelectionState({
  anchorKey: 'abc', // key of block
  anchorOffset: 5,
  focusKey: 'abc',
  focusOffset: 10, // key of block
  hasFocus: true,
  isBackward: false // isBackward = (focusOffset < anchorOffset)
});

let s = new SelectionState(selection);
editorState = EditorState.forceSelection(editorState, s);
// Make sure to set this new EditorState as the editorState of Draft.js component
```

Forcing the document to jump to this location is trickier, but running the following **after** Draft.js sets up the selection should do the trick:

```
window.getSelection().focusNode.parentElement.scrollIntoView();
window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement.scrollIntoView();
```

by "**after**" I mean that this should be put into a setTimeout or you should somehow hook into Draft.js internals